# depth of a child in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I have any way to know which is the depth of a child based on a container. 
Example:

```
<div id="dontainer">
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li id="xelement">3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

You should get 2 for "xelement" (taking as starting at 0). Knowing that the "li" are at the same level.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to find the depth of a child in a parent, given both? If so, it's as easy as iterating through all the child's parents until you hit the desired parent and keeping a count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the depth of a child in reference to some arbitrary ancestor.

```
function depth(parent, descendant) {
  var depth = 0;
  var el = $(descendant);
  var p = $(parent)[0];
  while (el[0] != p) {
    depth++;
    el = el.parent();
  }
  return depth;
}

// Example call:
depth(".mainContent", "li")
```

A complete solution will need to handle the case where the specified parent isn't an ancestor of descendant.

Alternatively, and only if you support ES5 and above, working directly with DOM nodes can eliminate the dependency on jQuery:

```
function depth(parent, descendant) {
    var depth = 0;
    while (!descendant.isEqualNode(parent)) {
      depth++;
      descendant = descendant.parentElement;
    }
    return depth;
}

// Example call:
depth(document.querySelector('.mainContent'), document.querySelector('li'))
```

Comment: We modify the example with "el[0]!=parent[0]" because ".not" removes the elements and we need to know if they are different.

Comment: Edited to add a vanilla javascript implementation

Answer (score 8):

```
$.fn.depth = function() {
  return $(this).parents().length;
};
```

or something like that.

Comment: oh wait - by "based on a container" you mean the depth relative to the container.  Well, you could get the depth of both and subtract, or use a filter expression like "#containerId *" in the first call.

Comment: For absolute depth in the tree I like this solution for jquery.
<body> ends up being at depth == 1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple recursive function, something along the lines of:
(While I do recommend using a toolkit, this is a good little learning game, bugs fixing left as an exercise for the readers.)

```
function countDepth(node, stopPredicate, count) {
  count = count || 0
  stopPredicate = stopPredicate || function () {}
  if (stopPredicate(node) || !node.parentNode) {
    return count
  }
  return countDepth(node.parentNode, stopPredicate, count + 1)
}

var depth = countDepth(document.getElementById("xelement"), function (node) {
  return "dontainer" == node.id
})

// or, with no predicate -- will count *full* depth
// depth = countDepth(document.getElementById("xelement"))

alert(depth)
```

Edit: If you are using jQuery, see the closest() function.