# JQuery find() with depth limit two seperate lists within eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex list of divs (using class searching) inside another complex list of divs and need a global way or grab those two lists as separate lists.

EG code:

```
<div id="ServicesAccordian" class="scaling-Accordian">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ACCPriority-3">
            something
        </div
        <div class="ACCPriority-3">
            something
        </div
        <div class="ACCPriority-3">
            <div id="ServicesAccordian" class="scaling-Accordian">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="ACCPriority-3">
                        something at second depth
                    </div
                    <div class="ACCPriority-3">
                        something at second depth
                    </div
                    <div class="ACCPriority-3">
                        something at second depth
                    </div
                </div>
            </div>
        </div
    </div>
</div>
```

I am searching first for all '.scaling-Accordians' as so:

```
this.AllAccordians = $('.scaling-Accordian');
```

Then I want to go through each accordion and grab all the rows without grabbing the inner rows as children:

```
this.AllRows = $(this.ACCORDIAN).find('[class^="row"], [class*=" row"]');
```

The problem this has is that the query returns the inner child rows for the second Accordion. I have tried using .Children() but this doesn't work because the rows, accordions, and ordering are at differing depths for different accordions. Plus class names are different and random depending on the list I am working on. The code needs to work for every accordion I make. However, I do know that the depth of the rows at maximum should be 4-6 branches and never should be deeper. I need a way to grab the scaling-Accordian and it's rows without grabbing the rows from the inner scaling-Accordian.

With the current search, my accordion for example with only 5 rows is picking up the inner rows as so:
[image: console log]

And if I try using the .Children() method to search one branch, it doesn't work because each accordion can have different depths, different id and classes and etc.
And if I try using the .not() method to ignore double depth branches, it also doesn't work because I still want the deeper accordion, just as a different list. The output for:

```
$(this.ACCORDIAN).find('[class^="row"], [class*=" row"]').not('.scaling-Accordian [class^="row"], [class*=" row"] .scaling-Accordian [class^="row"], [class*=" row"]');
```

is:

[image: console log]

I need a way to specify depth I want to limit to and grab the first accordion with 5 rows as 1 accordion, and then the accordions inside each of those rows as another 5 *separate* accordions. Is there any plugin maybe for searching specific depths?

Sorry if this is over-complicated or too confusing. I'll try to answer any questions. I just need something very specific for a general use case.

Thanks

EDIT:
A specific example of my accordions is:

```
<div id="ServicesAccordian" class="Scaling-Accordion">
    <!--RENDER: Card Body Accordian - ALL SERVICES-->
    <!--Item Card-->
    <div id="CardToHide4">
        <!--Item Card-->
        <div class="card">
            <!--Card Title-->
            <div class="card-header" id="heading_1">
                <div class="row collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_1">
                    <!--Card Title - Title Section-->
                    <div class="col-1 ACCPriority-3 text-center">
                        <span class="far fa-caret-square-down"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!--Card Title - Category Name-->
                    <div class="col-10 ACCPriority-1">
                        NAME
                    </div>
                    <!--Card Title - Total Price-->
                    <div class="col-1 ACCPriority-2 text-success text-right">
                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">
                                    $987.00
                                </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Card/Item - Body-->
            <div id="collapse_1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_1" data-parent="#ServicesAccordian">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!--Card Body Columns-->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <!--Entire Form-->
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <!--Products Accordian-->
                                <div class="Scaling-Accordion">
                                    <div class="row">

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PS, it's called **accordion**. And also **ID should be unique** `ServicesAccordian` That's where the name comes from: IDentifier

Comment: Can you please show a specific code and the specific expected result? It's a bit hard to follow up... 5 rows and than 5 rows as 1 and than 4, 6 branches... I'm lost. Instead of using images of logs, why not show the actual code that produces it?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sure. I'll edit on my original post. One moment

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just finding a really nice small depth check function from this post ([depth of a child in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596365/depth-of-a-child-in-the-dom)):

```
function depth(parent, descendant) {
    var depth = 0;
    var el = $(descendant);
    var p = $(parent)[0];
    while (el[0] != p) {
        depth++;
        el = el.parent();
    }
    return depth;
}
```

And then checking whether the row was too deep in context of the Scaling-Accordion class as so:

```
this.AllRows = $(this.ACCORDIAN).find('.row');
//Remove deep rows
for (var i = 0, ROW; ROW = this.AllRows[i++];) {
    var isToDeep = (depth(this.ACCORDIAN, ROW) > 5);
    if (isToDeep) {
        this.AllRows.splice(i - 1, 1);
    }
}
```

It works quite well and you can set any depth limit with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `.not()` function in jQuery, which modifies the original result set it retrieved so as not to include any that match the selector in `not()`.

In other words, you can specify, `$('.scaling-Accordian').not('.scaling-Accordian .scaling-Accordian')`.

Literally that would read as "Select all the elements with a class of 'scaling-Accordian' but don't include the items that match the class 'scaling-Accordian' which are children of another element with class 'scaling-Accordian'"

This way, you are telling jQuery to not include the items where that class is nested within itself.

Simplified example HTML:

```
<div class="accordian">
  <div class="anotherClass">
    <div class="accordian inner-accordian">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
console.log('Matches: ', $('.accordian').length);  //Matches: 2
console.log('Matches: ', $('.accordian').not('.accordian .accordian').length);  //Matches: 1
```

Comment: I'm looking for rows in the accordians: $(this.ACCORDIAN).find('.row') but this: $(this.ACCORDIAN).find('.row').not('.row .row'); doesn't work because then it doesn't grab the inner accordion. Remember, I want to get the outer accordion as one list with it's 5 rows, and for each row, there is another accordion I want to grab seperately. Each with 1 row in them.

Comment: Output for $(this.ACCORDIAN).find('.row').not('.row .row'); is still: https://imgur.com/DpPyraQ Also tried: $(this.ACCORDIAN).find('.row').not('.row .Scaling-Accordion .row'); which doesn't work either